# Http requests on iOS

Tags: ios, http, request

So i am trying to make an http request using ASIHTTPRequest class , to send a json file to my server. I was given an android code which is functional and was asked to convert it to iOS code.
I cant understand how to add headers on my request.The android code looks something like this :

```
private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
private static final String JSON_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
```

and then :

```
request.addHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, JSON_CONTENT_TYPE);
```

On iOS i figured out that the code is something like this :

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"Content-Type"];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Json-Content-Type" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"];
```

BUT i got a bit confused , cause on android the request seems to be paired and on iOS the requestHeaders are individually stated. Is this a problem? Should they be paired too on iOS. Am i missing something here? Thank you for reading my post :D

Comment: you should not use `ASIHTTPRequest` anymore because they stopped developing it. take a look at `AFNetworking` for example

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: thats why i made a comment, and not an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is

```
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json; charset=utf-8"];
```

in the android example, they are just declaring two variables for the header values, they could had simply done something like

```
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

which would have had the same effect, so you just need the one line i mentioned above.

also: `ASIHTTPREQUEST` does not get developed any more [(see headline here)](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), so consider using another library for something like this, like [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)

Comment: Thank you very much , i was trying to configure this out the last couple of hours..